# How do I assign exe output to a variable in gitlab ci scripts?

Tags: bash, svn, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When running my gitlab ci I need to check whether a specified svn directory exists.

I was using the script:

```
variables:
  DIR_CHECK: "default"

stages:
  - setup
  - test
  - otherDebugJob
  
.csharp:
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.cs"
      - "**/*.js"

setup:
  script:
    - $DIR_CHECK = $(svn ls https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal --depth empty)
    - echo $DIR_CHECK
test:
  script:
    - echo "DIR_CHECK is blank"
    - echo $DIR_CHECK
  rules:
    - if: $DIR_CHECK == ''

otherDebugJob:
  script:
    - echo "DIR_CHECK is not blank"
    - echo $DIR_CHECK
  rules:
    - if: $DIR_CHECK != ''
```

the svn command works and echos back the correct reply but *$DIR_CHECK* does not get set to anything but the original *default*.  It does not store the returned string from the svn command.

How do I store the returned string from an exe in a variable in gitlab ci?

Test run:

> Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00  $ $DIR_CHECK =
> $(svn ls https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal
> --depth empty)  svn: E170000: Illegal repository URL [https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal'](https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal%27)  $ echo
> $DIR_CHECK  Cleaning up file based variables 00:01  Job succeeded

Comment: Try `DIR_CHECK=$(your-command)` (no `$` and no spaces around the `=`).

Comment: @AdamMarshall, thanks for the suggestiom but the result was the same :-(

Comment: Oh, I misread your pipeline definition initially. When creating (or modifying) a variable in a single job, it only exists in that job. If you add your `echo $DIR_CHECK` in your `setup` job's script, it should show the output of the svn command. Then, when the `test` job runs, it uses the global variable since it doesn't otherwise exist in the `test` job.

Comment: I am not sure whether that worked - I have attached the test run above.  If that is the case how do I set a variable in one block and refer to it another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Passing variables between jobs

Unfortunately, you cannot use `DIR_CHECK` variable the way you described. List of steps to be executed generates before steps actually runs, that means for all of the steps `DIR_CHECK` will be equal to `default`. First of all there are few tips how you can pass variables between jobs:

**First way**

You can add desired command to the `before_script` section in your `.csharp` template:

```
.csharp:
  before_script:
    - export DIR_CHECK=$(svn ls https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal --depth empty)
```

and extend other steps with this `.csharp`.

**Second way**

You can pass variables between jobs with job artifacts:

```
setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - DIR_CHECK=$(svn ls https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal --depth empty)
    - echo "DIR_CHECK=$DIR_CHECK" > dotenv_file
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: 
        - dotenv_file
```

**Thirds way**
You can [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) or use [parent/child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#pass-cicd-variables-to-a-child-pipeline) to pass variables into pipelines.

```
staging:
  variables:
    DIR_CHECK: "you are awesome, guys!"
  stage: deploy
  trigger: my/deployment
```

In the triggered pipeline your variable will exists at the very start moment, and all the rules will be applied correctly.

## Solution

In your case, if you really don't want to include `otherDebugJob` step in your pipeline you can do the following:

**First approach**

This is quite easy way and this will work, but looks like not a best practice. So, we are already know how to pass our `DIR_CHECK` variable from `setup` step , just add some check in the `test` step `script` block:

```
script:
- |
  if [ -z "$DIR_CHECK" ]; then
    exit 0
  fi
- echo "DIR_CHECK is blank"
- echo $DIR_CHECK
```

Do the almost same thing for the `otherDebugJob` but check if `DIR_CHECK` is not empty with `if [ -n "$DIR_CHECK" ]`.

This approach is helpful when your pipeline not contains a lot of steps, but after the `test` and `otherDebugJob` follows another few steps.

**Second approach**

You can fail your `setup` step and then handle this fail in `otherDebugJob` step:

```
setup:
  script:
    - DIR_CHECK=$(svn ls https://server.fsl.local:port/svn/myco/personal/TestNotReal --depth empty)
    - |
      if [ -z "$DIR_CHECK" ]; then
        exit 1
      fi

otherDebugJob:
  script:
    - echo "DIR_CHECK is not blank"
  when: on_failure
```

This approach is useful if you only want to make some debug stuff after this `setup` step. After all `on_failure` jobs, pipeline will be marked as **Failed** and stopped.