# How to set variable value over ssh in gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set an environment variable for my GitLab Runner which value I retrieve using a ssh command. I tired to set the variable in the `workflow` like below. The problem is that the ssh command is not executed and is treated like a string.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: always
      variables:
        TABLE_STATUS: ssh gitlab-runner@$TARGET_HOST "source $DRIVE_PATH/config/.config && mysql -u $USER -p$PASSWORD -e \"SELECT IF(MONTH(datetime) = MONTH(NOW()), IF(status = 1, 'TRUE', 'FALSE'), 'FALSE') FROM schema.table WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name';\" "
        BRANCH: prod
        DRIVE_PATH: /path/to/prod
    - when: always
```

The ssh command works in script but I dont know how to assigne the value to a variable before script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly using a string command in your variable is indeed likely to result in...  a string value.

Executing the command should involve, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712144/6309), the subshell command `$(xxx)`.

In your case, from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249506/how-to-set-variable-value-over-ssh-in-gitlab-ci-yml-file/69249910#comment122397670_69249910), using the [`before_script` directive](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script):

```
before_script:
   TABLE_STATUS=$(ssh gitlab-runner@$TARGET_HOST "source $DRIVE_PATH/config/.config && mysql ...)
```

Comment: Using the `:` also results in a string. I changed it to `TABLE_STATUS=$(ssh ...` and moved it from `workflow` to `before_script`. This should work now. I accept the answer because the link you posted is what I was looking for.

Comment: @luigigi OK. I have amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: is there a way to set the env variable inside the script, I have variables that I want to keep just in my script scope

Comment: @moussaEL I haven't tested that use case. What did you see on your side? As long as those environment variables are set, they should be valid in script, no? See also "[GitLab environment variables demystified](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/04/09/demystifying-ci-cd-variables/)]" from [Veethika Mishra](https://twitter.com/veethikaa).