# Passing gitlab variables in sshpass script

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd, sshpass

Is there a way to add gitlab variables to the command ?

eg: variables: ARTIFACTORY_ADDRESS: "a.com"

script:

sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@SERVER 'echo $ARTIFACTORY_ADDRESS'

Currently its not taking the value from the variable and printing $ARTIFACTORY_ADDRESS in the console. I want the value to be printed in the console

Comment: Is this similar to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69249910/6309)?

Comment: No... I am not trying to save the ssh output in a variable. My ssh script is getting executed but I need to pass a gitlab variable to that ssh script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if using double-quotes would help enabling variable substitution:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@SERVER \
        "echo $ARTIFACTORY_ADDRESS"
       ^^^                       ^^^
```

Comment: Yeah adding double quotes worked